# I need to load the following data as a Serie object using read_csv

Tags: python, series

```
Date        Daily minimum temperatures in Melbourne, Australia  
1/1/1981    20.7    
1/2/1981    17.9    
1/3/1981    18.8    
1/4/1981    14.6    
1/5/1981    15.8    
1/6/1981    15.8    
1/7/1981    15.8
```

My code:

```py
from pandas import read_csv
filename = 'daily-minimum-temperatures-in-me.csv'
series=read_csv(filename,header=0,index_col=0,parse_dates=True,squeeze=True)
```

After execution, I get error.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem. Do you have the right indentation?

```
    from pandas import read_csv 
    filename = 'file.csv' 
    series=read_csv(filename,header=0,index_col=0,parse_dates=True,squeeze=True)
```

The csv-document is quiet suspicious.
I assume that the first element is the date and the second is the temperature? Therefore there must be a separator like ',' between this values. If the the first line (*Date Daily minimum temperatures in Melbourne, Australia*) is inside the csv file, you should avoid the ',' between Melbourne and Austrlia and maybe change the complete header to: data, temp

Comment: I copy and paste in notepad .when using this sample file it works for me.Can you try the complete file from this link?https://www.kaggle.com/paulbrabban/daily-minimum-temperatures-in-melbourne

Comment: I removed the last line of the file, that has more than 2 values separated by ','

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the last line of the file and it works.